# Troubleshooting HTML/PHP Form

Tags: php, html, forms, feedburner

I am using feedburner for my rss feeds and am currently trying to create a widget that displays the generic feedburner email subscribe form with a slight modification.  I am trying to include a text box in my form for a user to enter a keyword and then when they enter their email and hit subscribe they are brought to the feedburner confirmation page.

All is working well except for retreiving the variable I have set for the "keyword" text box..  technically after the form is filled out the confirmation url should look something like:
 **feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?=MYFEED&s=USER-KEYWORD**

but it currently just shows this:  **feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?=MYFEED&s=** 
- and the last little bit is left blank so I am looking for someone to tell me where I went wrong on getting the keyword text field to populate the url in the search parameter..

here is my form (with the mod):

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        $user_value = $_POST['keyword'];


        echo $before_widget;
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

            <form style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;text-align:center;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=MYFEED&s=<?php echo $user_value ?>" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=MYFEED&s=<?php echo $user_value ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">

<p>Enter a keyword:</p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $user_value ?>" /></p>

<p>Enter your email address:</p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email"/></p>

<input type="hidden" value="MYFEED" name="uri"/>

<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />

<p>Delivered by <a href="http://feedburner.google.com" target="_blank">FeedBurner</a></p></form>

        <?php echo $after_widget;
    }
```

**EDIT**
Most Recent Version (with var_dump):

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            var_dump($_POST);
            extract( $args );
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

              $user_value = $_POST['keyword'];


            echo $before_widget;
            if ( ! empty( $title ) )
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

                <form style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;text-align:center;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=MYFEED&s=<?php echo $user_value ?>" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=MYFEED&s=<?php echo $user_value ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">

<p>Enter a keyword:</p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $user_value ?>" /></p>

<p>Enter your email address:</p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email"/></p>

<input type="hidden" value="MYFEED" name="uri"/>

<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />

<p>Delivered by <a href="http://feedburner.google.com" target="_blank">FeedBurner</a></p></form>

            <?php echo $after_widget;
        }
```

Comment: You need `<?php echo $user_value ?>` in the `action` - you're missing the `echo`

Comment: Good point, I did do that just now and still couldnt get it to go through in the feedburner subscribe url?

Comment: Are you sure that $user_value is being set? Is the action still showing as blank?

Comment: Yep, just updated the above code so yo ucan see it in its entirety (aside from the feed name)

Answer (score 1):

Should be either

```
<?php echo $user_value ?>
      ^^^^---
```

or

```
<?= $user_value ?>
 ^^--
```

Comment: Tried that and it isnt working..  You can see the above code I updated to show the changes.. Maybe I am missing something else

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)`  and see if you're getting what you think you're getting.

Comment: so something similar to this:
'$user_value = $_POST['keyword'];
  var_dump($user_value);'

Comment: no. `var_dump($_POST)`. go right to the source. if what you want isn't in $_POST to start with, you'll never get it into $user_value

Comment: Im sorry if this is stupid question, I am still learning PHP but can you post a sample on how I would use it?  Anyway that I try it is not working and im 99% sure it is because I am not doing it right..

Comment: `public function widget() { var_dump($_POST); }`. that's all. call the widget function as your normally would and you'll get a dump of the contents of $_POST.

Comment: Im missing something here, I added it directly after the opening bracket after 'public function widget() { 
var_dump($_POST); 
.....all my other stuff ...
}'

Comment: Ok, can you please look at my most recent edit and tell me where I am going wrong?  Only other thing I could think of is me testing this on localhost but I wouldnt think that would effect anything??

Thank you for your help